# SQL sort grouped results based on a combination of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2 and I've been trying to figure out how to sort a table in a particular way. I want to return the results where the rows are grouped together by ID, but sorted by ParameterValue where ParameterName='PartToTest'.

For example, take this table. I need to sort on LM2736, TPS54226, BQ24190, etc keep the group of rows with common ID together.

```
ID              ParameterName   ParameterValue
========        =============   ==============
14635355        PartToTest      LM2736
14635355        PartType        Switcher
14635356        PartToTest      TPS54226
14635356        PartType        Other
14635357        PartToTest      BQ24190
14635357        PartType        Switcher
14635358        PartToTest      LM22677-Q1
14635358        PartType        LED
```

The result of the sort should be

```
ID              ParameterName   ParameterValue
========        =============   ==============
14635357        PartToTest      BQ24190
14635357        PartType        Switcher
14635358        PartToTest      LM22677-Q1
14635358        PartType        LED
14635355        PartToTest      LM2736
14635355        PartType        Switcher
14635356        PartToTest      TPS54226
14635356        PartType        Other
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired output please? what do you mean by "but sorted by ParameterValue where ParameterName='PartToTest'."

Comment: Sure. For each ID, there will be several rows of key/value pairs (more than what is shown here). I want to return the all the rows for all IDs, where the IDs are sorted by the value with the key 'PartToTest'. So the values for the key PartToTest in this example are LM2736, TPS54226, BQ24190, and LM22677-Q1. So sorted, it should return all rows with ID  14635357 (BQ24190) followed by all rows with ID 14635358 (LM22677-Q1) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be not the most efficient solution, but it returns correct result:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY
    MIN(CASE WHEN [ParameterName] = 'PartToTest' THEN [ParameterValue] ELSE NULL END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    ,ID
    ,ParameterName;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1233/1/0).

Comment: Thanks, this does what I'm looking for.